# Bluetooth device - switch between two laptops?

Tags: bluetooth, accessories

Anyone know of a device that allow or enable a Bluetooth device to switch between two laptops? I'm looking for a way to toggle a bluetooth device from one laptop to another laptop and back to the other and so on. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Not to confuse the question but I'm thinking of a monitor switch for a PC where one can switch between separate PCs on one 1 monitor - this concept except for Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tried this product. So the recommendation comes from the literature. Logitech M720 mouse and M780 keyboard are setup for pairing with up to three separate devices. The keyboard and mouse come with buttons to toggle between the three different paired devices.

Logitech M720: https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/m720-triathlon

Logitech M780 Keyboard: https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/k780-multi-device-wireless-keyboard?crid=27

Logitech Flow: https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options/page/flow-multi-device-control

If you are looking for Audio Device, the Bose QuiteComfort 35 II will store up to 8 device pairings, and allow for 2 active pairings. With either the Bose Connect app or the power switch, you can cycle through different devices.

Bose QuiteComfort 35 II: https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/over_ear_headphones/quietcomfort-35-wireless-ii.html#v=qc35_ii_black